# Bootstrap 3: Issue with blockquote

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem when i put this code :

```
<blockquote>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
  <footer>Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite></footer>
</blockquote>
```

its not working on my page but i have all files of css bootstrap 3 and jquery and the other things work fine like Dropdown for example only blockquote when i check blockquote in css file i found it there but i don't have the effect

Help and thanks !

Comment: According to you what is the expected and actual output? I mean what kind of effect are you expecting on `blockquote` and what is it that you are actually getting.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using version 3.1.0? Because this is a v3.1.0 feature (See [#11660](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11660)).
 If you are not using v3.1.0, then change `<footer>` to `<small>`

Comment: The probleme was solved by deleting a file of css he is the cause of the probleme thank you very mush

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine just tested it. Can you re-download the latest version of Bootstrap and try again please. And do post some of your code on how you added the file links. For Blockquote to work you only need Bootstrap.css file. So check again if you are overriding it in your CSS. Inspect the blockquote tag and check if any bootstrap style is getting applied or not.

```
<blockquote>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
  <footer>Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite></footer>
</blockquote>
```

Here is an example of your code. http://jsfiddle.net/f9djA/3/